# Load database data without reload without interval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to fetch data from database without reload but also without setting interval. I know that one way is with interval by:

```
setInterval(function(){

$("#someDiv").load("somefile.php");

}, 1000);
```

But is it possible to load div from page not whole page. Or if I need to load whole page how can it be done without setting interval...

Comment: What do you mean: "...load div from page not whole page..."?

Comment: so call load without the interval...

Comment: you probably mean something like a chat, or notification ,, where data comes from the server to the client without pulling .. you can do that with websockets. you push data to the client.

Comment: If you are looking to fetch data from database, that means you have to make multiple request. Which can be done in 2 ways, either you use for loop with some timer or setInternal. Not preferring using reload the page, just for my own references

Comment: @NetaMeta yeah for chat... I had with interval but 1000ms was slow and i put like 100ms which can make server crash. I wanted to know way without interval. Do you have some websocket example or questions with that on stackoverflow? I was looking a lot but I dodnt find, maybe i am little wordless with searching..

Comment: websockets is a whole subject to its self you gonna have to research and learn about it. i cant give you a quick example.